# UWP Animate ViewBox scale

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a TextBlock that is being down scaled by a ViewBox so longer texts are shown completely without linebreaks.

When this text changes in length I'd like to animate the height change of the ViewBox / TextBlock to avoid jarring jumps. I'm fading out/in the Textblock on content changes so the actual text change looks nice, just the height impacts other controls.

Is there a way to react to scale changes in the ViewBox and animate this? Or maybe there's already a UWP-compatible control out there?

Comment: You could create `DoubleAnimation` in `ViewBox` Size change `SizeChanged` and animation ViewBox Height property.

Comment: isn't the SizeChanged event fired after the resize has already happened?